# Time complexity of a tree to find the vertex using BFS algo

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, breadth-first-search

[image]

I am little bit confused about BFS time complexity for tree.If there have n no of child of a parent node then What will be the time complexity to find the value?

## for example :-

It is the graph image.I want to find vertex "K" by using BFS algo then what will be the time complexity? please explain it .

Answer (score 0):

- Here the above tree data structure is same as Non-directed, Non-weighted, simple graph.
- As of your question we can start the BFS algorithm from A vertex to K vertex, we will get path A->B->C->D->E->F->G->H->I->J->K
- Queue data structure is more convenient while finding vertex by BFS.
- Complexity calculation:

1) The complexity of BFS implemented using an Adjacency Matrix will be O(|V|^2). 
Reason: In adjacency matrix you need to visit one node twice as they are repeating in row and column.

2) When implemented by an Adjacency List is O(|V| + |E|).
Reason: Because of adjacency list we just need to visit the vertex once.

Comment: okk ..then for this tree complexity will be O(v+E).fine,bt when was browsing on net ,i found something like O(b^d) for that ...here is link ...then what is this =>>>http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.034b/searchcomplex.pdf .... thanks @chintan shah